# Functional programming: How to carry on the context for a chain of validation rules

Tags: java, scala, haskell, functional-programming, kotlin

I have a set of functions (rules) for validation which take a context as parameter and either return "Okay" or an "Error" with a message. Basically these could return a `Maybe` (Haskell) / `Optional` (Java) type.

In the following I would like to validate properties of a `Fruit` (the context) and return an error message if the validation failed, otherwise "Okay"/Nothing.

Note:
I would prefer a solution that is purely functional style and stateless/immutable. It is a bit of a Kata, actually.

For my experiments I used Kotlin, but the core problem also applies to any language that supports higher order functions (such as Java and Haskell).
You can find a [link to the full source code here](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/d5hlc3nta19e3i6acgq1fqgj1g/anrp1iip26tp7bel24icf6gqq) and the same at the very bottom.

Given a Fruit class with color and weight, plus some example rules:

```
data class Fruit(val color:String, val weight:Int)

fun theFruitIsRed(fruit: Fruit) : Optional<String> =
        if (fruit.color == "red") Optional.empty() else Optional.of("Fruit not red")
fun fruitNotTooHeavy(fruit: Fruit) : Optional<String> =
            if (fruit.weight < 500) Optional.empty() else Optional.of("Too heavy")
```

Now I would like to chain the rule evaluation using a reference to the respective *function*, without specifying the context as an argument using a `FruitRuleProcessor`.
When processing a rule fails, it should not evaluate any of the other rules.

For Example:

```
fun checkRules(fruit:Fruit) {
  var res = FruitRuleProcessor(fruit).check(::theFruitIsNotRed).check(::notAnApple).getResult()
  if (!res.isEmpty()) println(res.get())
}

def main(args:Array<String) { 
  // "Fruit not red": The fruit has the wrong color and the weight check is thus skipped
  checkRules(Fruit("green","200"))
  //  Prints "Fruit too heavy": Color is correct, checked weight (too heavy)
  checkRules(Fruit("red","1000")) 
 }
```

I do not care where it failed, only about the result. Also when a function returns an error, the others should not be processed.
Again, this pretty much sounds like an `Optional` Monad.

Now the problem is that somehow I have to carry the `fruit` context from `check` to `check` call.

One solution I tried is to implement a `Result` class that takes a context as value and has two subclasses `RuleError(context:Fruit, message:String)` and `Okay(context)`. The difference to `Optional` is that now I can wrap around the `Fruit` context (think `T = Fruit`)

```
// T: Type of the context. I tried to generify this a bit.
sealed class Result<T>(private val context:T) {

    fun isError () = this is RuleError

    fun isOkay() = this is Okay

    // bind
    infix fun check(f: (T) -> Result<T>) : Result<T> {
        return if (isError()) this else f(context)
    }

    class RuleError<T>(context: T, val message: String) : Result<T>(context)

    class Okay<T>(context: T) : Result<T>(context)
}
```

I think that this looks like a monoid/Monad, with `return` in the constructor lifting a `Fruit` into a `Result` and `or` being the `bind`. Although I tried some Scala and Haskell, admittedly I am not so experienced with that.

Now we can change the rules to

```
fun theFruitIsNotTooHeavy(fruit: Fruit) : Result<Fruit> =
    if (fruit.weight < 500) Result.Okay(fruit) else Result.RuleError(fruit, "Too heavy")

fun theFruitIsRed(fruit: Fruit) : Result<Fruit> =
    if (fruit.color == "red") Result.Okay(fruit) else Result.RuleError(fruit, "Fruit not red")
```

which allows to chain checks like intended:

```
fun checkRules(fruit:Fruit) {
    val res = Result.Okay(fruit).check(::theFruitIsRed).check(::theFruitIsNotTooHeavy)
    if (res.isError()) println((res as Result.RuleError).message)
}
```

// Prints:
Fruit not red
Too heavy

However this has one major drawback: The `Fruit` context now becomes part of the validation result, although it is not strictly necessary in there.

So to wrap it up: I'm looking for a way

- to carry the `fruit` context when invoking the functions
- so that I can chain (basically: compose) multiple checks in a row using the the same method
- along with the results of the rule functions *without changing the interface* of these.
- without side-effects

What functional programming patterns could solve this problem? Is it Monads as my gut feeling tries to tell me that?

I would prefer a solution that can be done in Kotlin or Java 8 (for bonus points), but answers in other languages (e.g. Scala or Haskell) also could be helpful. (It's about the concept, not the language :) )

You can find the full source code from this question in [this fiddle](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/d5hlc3nta19e3i6acgq1fqgj1g/anrp1iip26tp7bel24icf6gqq).

Comment: I can't read Kotlin code, but from skimming the problem description, it seems like the central computation you need is `Maybe`, or possibly `Either`. If you want to carry around read-only state in an implicit manner (instead of just passing it as an argument), you could use the the `Reader` monad. This would imply that you'd need to stack `Reader` on top of `Maybe`, or the other way around, so you you could consider `ReaderT` or `MaybeT` (alternatively `EitherT`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use/create a monoid wrapper of your `Optional`/`Maybe` type such as [`First`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:First) in Haskell which combines values by returning the first non-Nothing value.

I don't know Kotlin, but in Haskell it would look like this:

```
import Data.Foldable (foldMap)
import Data.Monoid (First(First, getFirst))

data Fruit = Fruit { color :: String, weight :: Int }

theFruitIsRed :: Fruit -> Maybe String
theFruitIsRed (Fruit "red" _) = Nothing
theFruitIsRed _               = Just "Fruit not red"

theFruitIsNotTooHeavy :: Fruit -> Maybe String
theFruitIsNotTooHeavy (Fruit _ w)
    | w < 500   = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just "Too heavy"

checkRules :: Fruit -> Maybe String
checkRules = getFirst . foldMap (First .)
    [ theFruitIsRed
    , theFruitIsNotTooHeavy
    ]
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/4Gk5Rh)

Note that I'm taking advantage of the `Monoid` instance of functions here:

```
Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)
```

Comment: Real cool but what does `(First(First, getFirst))` mean at the `import Data.Monoid ` stage.

Comment: @Redu "Import the type `First`, the data constructor `First`, and the record field `getFirst`." The parentheses associate the data constructor and field with the type.

Comment: @4castle Why keep only the `First` error instead of keeping all of them with `[]`?

Comment: @HTNW The OP said *"Also when a function returns an error, the others should not be processed."* but you could get that behavior by using [`catMaybes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes).

Answer (score 3):

Since the type of the object being validated can't change (as the object itself shouldn't change), I wouldn't use a monad (or any sort of functor). I'd have a type `Validator a err = a -> [err]`. If a validator succeeds, it outputs `[]` (no error). This forms a monoid, where `mzero = const []` and `` mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x ``. Haskell has this built in as `instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)`

**EDIT**: I appear to have misread the question. @4castle's answer is almost exactly this one but uses `Maybe err` instead of `[err]`. Use that.

```scala
// Scala, because I'm familiar with it, but it should translate to Kotlin
case class Validator[-A, +Err](check: A => Seq[Err]) {
  def apply(a: A): Err = check(a)
  def |+|[AA >: A](that: Validator[A, Err]): Validator[AA, Err]
  = Validator { a =>
    this(a) ++ that(a)
  }
}
object Validator {
  def success[A, E]: Validator[A, E] = Validator { _ => Seq() }
}

type FruitValidator = Validator[Fruit, String]
val notTooHeavy: FruitValidator = Validator { fruit =>
  if(fruit.weight < 500) Seq() else Seq("Too heavy")
  // Maybe make a helper method for this logic
}

val isRed: FruitValidator = Validator { fruit =>
  if (fruit.color == "red") Seq() else Seq("Not red")
}

val compositeRule: FruitValidator = notTooHeavy |+| isRed
```

To use, just call a `Validator` like `compositeRule(Fruit("green", 700))`, which returns 2 errors in this case.

To see why the reader monad is inappropriate here, consider what happens if

```hs
type Validator = ReaderT Fruit (Either String) Fruit
ruleA :: Validator
ruleA = ReaderT $ \fruit ->
  if color fruit /= "red" then Left "Not red"
  else Right fruit
ruleB :: Validator
ruleB = ReaderT $ \fruit ->
   if weight fruit >= 500 then Left "Too heavy"
   else Right fruit
ruleC = ruleA >> ruleB

greenHeavy = Fruit "green" 700
```

Both `ruleA` and `ruleB` fail for `greenHeavy`, yet running `runReaderT ruleC greenHeavy` only produces the first error. This is undesirable: you likely want as many errors as possible revealed per run.

Also, you can "hijack" the validation:

```hs
bogusRule :: ReaderT Fruit (Either String) Int
bogusRule = return 42

ruleD = do ruleA
           ruleB
           bogusRule -- Validates just fine... then throws away the Fruit so you can't validate further.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of Haskell implementations,
so let's try to solve it with Kotlin.

First, we start with the Data-Object:

```
class Fruit(val color: String, val weight: Int)
```

And we need a Type that represents a Fruit and whether an error occurred:

```
sealed class Result<out E, out O> {
    data class Error<E>(val e: E) : Result<E, Nothing>()

    data class Ok<O>(val o: O): Result<Nothing, O>()
}
```

Now lets define the Type of a FruitRule:

```
typealias FruitRule = (Fruit) -> String?
```

The `FruitRule` is a function that receives a Fruit-Instance
and returns `null` if the rule passed or the error message.

The problem we got here is that `FruitRule` itself is not composable.
So we need a Type that is composable and runs a `FruitRule` on a `Fruit`

```
typealias ComposableFruitRule = (Result<String, Fruit>) -> Result<String, Fruit>
```

First, we need a way to create a `ComposableFruitRule` from a `FruitRule`

```
fun createComposableRule(f: FruitRule): ComposableFruitRule {
    return { result: Result<String, Fruit> ->

        if(result is Result.Ok<Fruit>) {
            val temporaryResult = f(result.o)

            if(temporaryResult is String)
                Result.Error(temporaryResult)
            else
                //We know that the rule passed,
                //so we can return Result.Ok<Fruit> we received back
                result
        } else {
            result
        }
    }
}
```

`createComposableFruitRule` returns a lambda that first checks whether the provided Result is `Result.Ok`. If yes, it runs the provided `FruitRule` on the given `Fruit` and returns `Result.Error` if the error message is not null.

Now lets make our `ComposableFruitRule` composable:

```
infix fun ComposableFruitRule.composeRules(f: FruitRule): ComposableFruitRule {
    return { result: Result<String, Fruit> ->
        val temporaryResult = this(result)

        if(temporaryResult is Result.Ok<Fruit>) {
            createComposableRule(f)(temporaryResult)
        } else {
            temporaryResult
        }
    }
}
```

This infix-function composes a `ComposableFruitRule` together with a `FruitRule`, that means first the internal `FruitRule` is invoked. If there is no error, the `FruitRule` provided as a parameter is invoked.

So now we are able to compose `FruitRules` together and afterward just provide a `Fruit` and check the rules.

```
fun colorIsRed(fruit: Fruit): String? {
    return if(fruit.color == "red")
        null
    else
        "Color is not red"
}

fun notTooHeavy(fruit: Fruit): String? {
    return if(fruit.weight < 500)
        null
    else
        "Fruit too heavy"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val ruleChecker = createComposableRule(::colorIsRed) composeRules ::notTooHeavy
    //We can compose as many rules as we want
    //e.g. ruleChecker composeRules ::fruitTooOld composeRules ::fruitNotTooLight

    val fruit1 = Fruit("blue", 300)
    val result1 = ruleChecker(Result.Ok(fruit1))
    println(result1)

    val fruit2 = Fruit("red", 700)
    val result2 = ruleChecker(Result.Ok(fruit2))
    println(result2)

    val fruit3 = Fruit("red", 350)
    val result3 = ruleChecker(Result.Ok(fruit3))
    println(result3)
}
```

The Output of that `main` is:

```
Error(e=Color is not red)
Error(e=Fruit too heavy)
Ok(o=Fruit@65b54208)
```

Comment: This is really nice!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it Monads as my gut feeling tries to tell me that?

I think `Monad` is too strong a requirement in your case. Your validation functions

> fun theFruitIsRed(fruit: Fruit) : Optional< String>

don't return an useable value when they validate successfully. And a defining characteristic of `Monad` is being able do decide what future computations to execute based on a previous result. "If the first validator succeeds returning foo, validate this field, if it succeeds returning bar, validate this other field instead".

I'm not knowledgeable about Kotlin, but I think you could have a `Validator<T>` class. It basically would wrap a single validation function for a type `T` that returned an `Optional<String>`.

Then you could write a method that combined two validators into a composite validator. The inner function of the composite validator would receive a T, run the first validator, return the error if it fails, if not run the second validator. (If your validators returned some useful result on successful validation, like say non-fatal warnings, you would need to supply an additional function to combine these results.)

The idea its that you would *first* compose the validators, and only *then* supply the actual T to get the final result. This compose-before-running approach is used by Java's [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-), for example.

Notice that in this solution, even if your functions returned some result on successful validation, those values would not be used to select what *validations* to do next (though an error would stop the chain). You could combine results using a function but that's it. This "more rigid" style of programming is called `Applicative` in Haskell. All types supporting a `Monad` interface can be used in an `Applicative` way, but some types support `Applicative` without supporting `Monad`.

---

Another interesting aspect of validators is that they are contravariant on their input type `T`. This means that you can "pre-apply" a function from `A` to `B` to a `Validator<B>`, resulting in a `Validator<A>` whose type went "backwards" compared to the direction of the function. (The [`mapping`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) function of Java's `Collectors` class works this way.)

And you can go further down this route by having functions that build a validator for a composite out of validators for their individual parts. (What in Haskell is called [`Divisible`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.4/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Divisible.html).)

Answer (score 1):

To answer generally the question

> Now the problem is that somehow I have to carry the fruit context from check to check call.

...phrased as...

> Given some monad `M`, how do I chain some `M` actions while also (implicitly) giving the same “context” object to each?

The Haskell answer would be to use the [`ReaderT` monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#t:ReaderT). It takes any monad, such as `Maybe`, and gives you another monad which implicitly passes a “global constant” to each action.

Let me rewrite your checkers in Haskell:

```hs
data Fruit = Fruit {colour::String, weight::Int}

theFruitIsRed :: Fruit -> Either String ()
theFruitIsRed fruit
  | colour fruit == "red"  = Right ()
  | otherwise              = Left "Fruit not red"

fruitNotTooHeavy :: Fruit -> Either String ()
fruitNotTooHeavy fruit
  | weight fruit < 500     = Right ()
  | otherwise              = Left "Too heavy"
```

Note that I've used `Either String ()` instead of `Maybe String` because I want `String` to be the “abort case”, whereas in the `Maybe` monad it would be the “carry on” case.

Now, instead of doing

```hs
checks :: Fruit -> Either String ()
checks fruit = do
    theFruitIsRed fruit
    fruitNotTooHeavy fruit
```

I can do

```hs
checks = runReaderT $ do
    ReaderT theFruitIsRed
    ReaderT fruitNotTooHeavy
```

Your `Result` class seems to be essentially a special instantiation of the `ReaderT` transformer. Not sure if you could implement the exact thing in Kotlin as well.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for an error monad. Its like the `Maybe` (aka `Option`) monad, but the error case carries a message.

In Haskell its just the `Either` type, with the first argument being the type of the error value.

```
type MyError a = Either String a
```

If you check the [Data.Either](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html) documentation you will see that `Either e` is already an instance of Monad, so you don't need to do anything else. You can just write:

```
notTooHeavy :: Fruit -> MyError ()
notTooHeavy fruit = 
    when (weight fruit > 500) $ fail "Too heavy"
```

What the monad instance does is stop the computation at the first `fail`, so you get e.g. `Left "Too heavy"` or `Right ()`. If you want to accumulate errors then you have to do somthing more complicated.

Other posters have suggested that you don't need monads because your example code has all the functions returning `()`. While this may be true of your examples, I'm reluctant to generalise that fast. Also since you get the monadic instance automatically with `Either` it makes sense to just use it.